# Where to store mp4 files on a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, video-streaming

I am building some kind of video streaming web app using node.js/express and MongoDB. But I am facing an issue related to where to store the mp4 files that my clients will upload to my back-end. I am not sure if MongoDB is capable of storing large files(in the GB order) and my current idea is to keep the files on a directory and then keep track of each file path on MongoDB. Is this a good idea or is there a better method to do so?

Answer (score 3):

My advice, use
[s3.amazonaws.com](http://s3.amazonaws.com)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's way better to store only a path inside a MongoDB instead of storing directly the video file inside the DB. Because your DB will grow up so fast if you did that. The disk space taken by both solutions is the same, but overloading your DB with these files will just result in a slower DB result

Comment: It will grow about the exact same amount as the files on disk...

Comment: Sure! But why growing your DB size uselessly? Bigger your DB is, slower the result will show up. So, yes the size taken is exactly the same, but your DB will run slower